# Почему оба сервера в режиме active при кластеризации Pacemaker Corosync?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos7, cluster

Пытаюсь настроить HA между двумя серверами которые расположены на разных цодах разных компаний.

Так как нет возможности использовать IP адреса из одной подсети с одиным общим шлюзом, поднял S2S IPSec туннель между серверами, через туннель проходить идентичная сеть между серверами 10.11.12.0/27.

На серверах поднять кластер Pacemaker Corosync, но оба сервера считают себя активными хотя синхронизация и авторизация по PCS проходит. Но при выводе pcs status corosync выводится только локальный хост

-------------------------------NODE-1------------------------------------------------

```
[root@NODE-1 /]# pcs status nodes
Pacemaker Nodes:
Online: dyu.lb.server
Standby:
Maintenance:
Offline: huj.lb.server
Pacemaker Remote Nodes:
Online:
Standby:
Maintenance:
Offline:

[root@NODE-1 /]# pcs status
Cluster name: lbcluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: dyu.lb.server (version 1.1.20-5.el7_7.1-3c4c782f70) - partition WITHOUT quorum
Last updated: Thu Oct 31 09:33:04 2019
Last change: Thu Oct 31 09:16:59 2019 by root via cibadmin on dyu.lb.server

2 nodes configured
2 resources configured

Online: [ dyu.lb.server ]
OFFLINE: [ huj.lb.server ]

Full list of resources:

virtual_ip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2): Started dyu.lb.server
webserver (ocf::heartbeat:nginx): Started dyu.lb.server

Daemon Status:
corosync: active/enabled
pacemaker: active/enabled
pcsd: active/enabled

[root@NODE-1 /]# pcs status corosync

Membership information
----------------------
Nodeid Votes Name
1 1 dyu.lb.server (local)
```

-------------------------------NODE-2------------------------------------------------

```
[root@NODE-2 ~]# pcs status nodes
Pacemaker Nodes:
Online: huj.lb.server
Standby:
Maintenance:
Offline: dyu.lb.server
Pacemaker Remote Nodes:
Online:
Standby:
Maintenance:
Offline:

[root@NODE-2 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: lbcluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: huj.lb.server (version 1.1.20-5.el7_7.1-3c4c782f70) - partition WITHOUT quorum
Last updated: Thu Oct 31 09:33:13 2019
Last change: Thu Oct 31 09:15:42 2019 by root via cibadmin on huj.lb.server

2 nodes configured
0 resources configured

Online: [ huj.lb.server ]
OFFLINE: [ dyu.lb.server ]

No resources

Daemon Status:
corosync: active/enabled
pacemaker: active/enabled
pcsd: active/enabled

[root@NODE-2 ~]# pcs status corosync

Membership information
----------------------
Nodeid Votes Name
2 1 huj.lb.server (local)
```

Answer (score 0):

При кластеризации или вообщем при создании Virtual IP или VRRP нужно чтобы оба сервера были на одном broadcas домене.
Проблему можно решить подняв между серверами GRE туннель.